Preposition to be used after 'beg'
Following are three sentences, each one different from the other in their syntax of preposition . Which one of them is correct?

I beg a loan of him.
I beg a loan from him.
I beg for a loan from him.

I have seen a similar kind of question asked in this platform, but I couldn't clarify my doubt from the answers posted there because one said that "beg from (somebody) isn't very common" and the other indicated that "'beg from' is followed by a range or group"
Differences between {beg / beg for / beg of / beg from}
For example:
I beg from the rich.
But, while googling this, I came across a webpage which said beg of and beg from somebody has the same usage.
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/beg
Therefore, I want to know what is exactly technically correct as well as most acceptable. I would highly appreciate it if the proper reason could also be mentioned.
Thanks.

Apart from "frozen forms" such as I beg your pardon ("Excuse me" or "What did you say?") native Anglophones don't use beg much these days. Except pejoratively in the context of street beggars, etc. Consequently they might be a bit vague about whether a preposition is needed at all in some contexts.

The OP's linked examples about "begging somebody" are typically used to show an extreme emotional state (or feigned one).

@FumbleFingers - I begged the neighbour to start drilling holes in their walls after 8 AM; I was heading to Cambodia to do some charity work there. 'Three months will fly by,' I reassured Thomas as he begged me not to go.

You don't mean "beg a loan off him" which sounds possible although not very idiomatic?

The linked question is about beg from someone to do something, which is not correct - it's beg someone to do it.
The example that Oxford Learners gives is beg something of/from someone (ask them to give you that thing). It's correct that either preposition is acceptable, though this shows that of is much more usual.

If I say "beg of someone to do something" Will it be correct?

See the answer to the linked question! It's just about acceptable, but sounds old-fashioned.

to beg someone for something:
I begged him for a loan.
I begged them to do the work.
I beg [of] you: Stop repeating those rumours.
beg from is a no-go usually:
BUT: Who did they beg the money from?
They begged money from passers-by.

They were begging on streetcorners for money.
They were begging for money on streetcorners.

You beg a person and beg for something.

But I think beg of is frequently used as is mentioned in the other answer

"They were begging from passers-by" ('for money' is implied).
